# how to Integrating Bootstrap with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am constantly getting such an error message, what can I do for that?

[image]

Comment: You must include source code and not print screen.s

Answer (score 0):

You are probably `requiring` the bootstrap URL. There is no need for that.

You either use the `vue-boostrap` package or include the necessary files in your index.html via old plain HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Bootstrap3 and not Bootstrap4. From the issue that you have shown, it looks like you have made some changes to package.json dependencies section and have not rerun npm install. Can you do that and retry?